# Data not being received

Tags: python, tcp

The following Python code opens a TCP connection between two machines, transfers a short string message, and then terminates the connection.  For some reason, however, the data isn't making it through.  The connection seems to work, but the data doesn't come through.  What am I doing wrong?

Server:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (IP, 10000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(28)
            print('received "%s"' % data)
            if data:
                print(data)
            else:
                print('no more data from', client_address)
                break
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Client:

```
def Data_Out(Status):
        Exists =  os.path.exists('/run/thermostat/outsideIP')
        if Exists:
                with open("/run/thermostat/outsideIP", "r") as f:
                        IP = f.read()
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                # Connect the socket to the port on the server
                server_address = (IP, 10000)
                try:
                        socket.create_connection(server_address, timeout=10)
                except socket.timeout as err:
                        return err
                if Status == 0:
                        message = '[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]\n'
                elif Status == 1:
                        message = '[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]\n'
                else:
                        message = '[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]\n'
                try:
                        sock.sendall(message)
                finally:
                        sock.close()
                        return 0
        else:
                return -1
```

Server Response:

```
HVAC-Relay1:/usr/local/sbin# TClient.py 
starting up on 192.168.1.34 port 10000
waiting for a connection
received "b''"
no more data from ('192.168.1.28', 46380)
waiting for a connection
```

Client Response:

```
pi@Thermostat-Office:/usr/local/sbin $ DISPLAY=:0 Relay_Sync.py 
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the socket expects a bytestream, not a string:

```
import pickle
        data = pickle.dumps(message)
        sock.sendall(data)
```